# What webserver I must use for deploying Angular application?

Tags: angular, deployment, webserver, vps

I have created an Angular application and like to deploy my project on a virtual private server(VPS). I followed this instruction https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback , and in the server configuration part, I saw there is many options like Apache, Nginx, Ruby, etc.

As I am using CentOS 8 on my VPS, what web server should I use and which one is best for Angular deployment? (I also must mention that I use NodeJS and MongoDB for my website backend).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Nginx server. For hosting static sites like angular applications its good option.